# Purpose of the question tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Does anyone think the tag of `question` is appropriate? Is it there for folks to use when they can't think of a category or are too lazy to look for an existing one that matches? I don't know any other SE sites that do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a carry over from the social sound design days when half of the site was a third party site that didn't just ask questions.  Presumably idea and possibly critique fall in to the same category, though to an extent we still allow critiques, so idea would be more of a questionable tag.  Either way, I've removed question from all of the questions it was used on and have removed the tag.  I did the same for not-a-question which was in the same boat (and locked the relevant posts as historically significant).